# callback(x + y) function signature confusion

Tags: javascript, callback

I was following along a Kyle Simpson async lecture and he was explaining the concept of a synchronous thunk and how it can be extended to async. He used the following code example with slight modifications:

```
function addAsync(x, y, cb) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        cb(x + y);
    }, 1000);
}

var asyncThunk = function(cb) {
    addAsync(10, 15, cb);
};

asyncThunk(function(sum) {
    console.log(sum);
});
```

I'm confused about the line cb(x + y) specifically.
So the way I understand this is an addAsync function takes 3 arguments including a callback and uses a setTimeout to simulate an async operation that takes 1 second. Inside, it invokes the cb function with x + y (back to this in a minute).

Then, asyncThunk defines another function that also takes a callback as its only argument and then calls addAsync with hard-assigned values for x and y. (At this point, the actual value that will be passed in as cb to both addAsync and asyncThunk aren't determined).

Finally, we call asyncThunk with the value *sum* which sets the cb arguments for asyncThunk and as a result, for addAsync. addAsync executes with the following arguments (10, 15, sum). Now, I don't really understand why the cb(x + y) syntax looks like that. f(x + y) isn't a function signature I've ever seen before I don't think. Don't you usually call functions with a comma separated list of arguments or no arguments at all?

For instance, This is how I would write the same program with syntax I understand

```
function addAsync(x, y, cb) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        cb(x, y);
    }, 1000);
}

var asyncThunk = function(cb) {
    addAsync(10, 15, cb);
};

asyncThunk(sum);

function sum(x, y) {
    console.log(x + y);
}
```

Comment: x + y, in your first snippet, is the same as 2 + 2

Comment: `f(x + y)` _is_ a comma-separated list of arguments, but there's only one and the trailing comma is optional.

Comment: **Finally, we call asyncThunk with the value sum** No. We're calling `asyncThunk` with a callback function as the argument. `sum` is the name of the parameter to the callback function.

Comment: `sum` will receive the value of `x+y` when the callback is called.

Comment: Are you confused that they did not use a named function? And the original code did some work, and you moved it to your callback, seems odd you would do that since the two code blocks now have totally different functionality. The `addAsync` is like a black box. You pass in some data and when it is done, it calls your function with a value.

Comment: @Barmar Can you explain how this works? So in the first example, sum is just the name of a callback function, and then that callback function gets called with cb(x + y). x + y is the first and only argument. How does cb then take on the value of x + y? Why does logging sum = 25?

Comment: No, sum is the _parameter_ to an unnamed function. The callback function _is_ cb, it gets called _with_ x + y.

Comment: @jonrsharpe ohh ok, I've been awake too long. Thanks. That clears up my confusion

Answer (score 0):

The difference between the two codes are where the responsibility for adding the numbers is done. Your version moves it from `addAsync` to `sum`. But the name `addAsync` implies that the function is supposed to do addition; you could have another function `subAsync` that does subtraction instead. Also, you can have different callback functions, without them knowing what the operation is.

For instance, below I also call `asyncThunk()` with a different callback that alerts instead of logging. The callback function doesn't care how the result is calculated, it just does something with the result.

Calling the parameter `sum` was misleading, because there's nothing about the callback that requires it to be a sum. It's any value that some other function can calculate.

```js
function addAsync(x, y, cb) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    cb(x + y);
  }, 1000);
}

var asyncThunk = function(cb) {
  addAsync(10, 15, cb);
};

asyncThunk(function(value) {
  console.log(value);
});

asyncThunk(function(value) {
  alert(value);
});
```